# Crystal Report BLOB Field Formula Evalution

Tags: text, crystal-reports, blob

I have two fields on a report, one is **Text field** and other is **Image field**.

I want to re-position **Text filed** on the biases of **Image field** value.

If **Image field** has no value then the Top of **Image Filed** should be assigned to **Text field**
Else If **Image field** has value then **Text filed** should be displayed at the bottom of **Image field**.

I am not getting how to evaluate a **BLOB** field in formula editor.

Can anybody suggest ?

Comment: what do you mean by `image field has value`?

Comment: Means, That BLOB filed contains image data.